# layout:set not working properly (EE 2.9)

Tags: template-layouts

Working with layout, have a problem:

```
{layout="_global/layout_cat"}
{exp:channel:entries channel="my_channel"}
    {layout:set name='htitle' value='{title} | some text'}
    Some text using the channel entry field values {title} {description}, etc.... 
{/exp:channel:entries}
{layout:set name="layout_param"}
 <script type="text/javascript">...some js script...</script>
{/layout:set}
```

When I look at the page, I see everything right, but also I see the parts of layout:set values, for example the half of {title} and "some text" then, including a '"}' at the end, and some parts of javascript insertions at the end.

What am I doing wrong?
No plugins installed, clean EE Core 2.9.2

Answer (score 0):

Got the problem myself;

In system/libraries/Template.php there is a function process_layout_template() 
It is working with strlen() & strpos() functions. Both are known as big trouble when working with multibyte strings. So I changed my VirtualHost settings:

```
# from:
php_admin_value mbstring.func_overload 2
# to 
php_admin_value mbstring.func_overload 0
```

Now everything is working perfect, cause strlen is getting the right count of the letters for the end of {layout:set} when parsing templates.